# Amazon Linux LAMP with php 5.5

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, lamp

I installed PHP 5.5 on my Amazon Linux VPS via the [instructions here](http://webtatic.com/packages/php55/).  The CLI is working fine.

I also had apache already installed and running via the `httpd` package.  It was running without any issue.

I see that there is no `mod_php` in the list of available modules.  Now when I try to restart `httpd` I get the error:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 222 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: symbol SSLeay_version, version OPENSSL_1.0.1 not defined in file libcrypto.so.10 with link time reference

I've looked up parts of this error, and the general advice seems to be to run

```
yum update openssl
```

However, when I run this I just get:

> No packages marked for update

When I run `install` instead of `update`, I get:

> Package 1:openssl-1.0.1e-4.55.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
>   Nothing to do

I'm not sure what else to do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The `php55` package in the Amazon Linux YUM repository requires the `http24` package, not the `http` package.

Comment: Actually the problem was that I needed to use the `php55` package in the first place instead of using those CentOS instructions.  Amazon's `php55` package includes `httpd24`